# How to count objects from m2m connection

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have a problem with understanding of how to count objects from m2m connection in django. I need to get number of photos in photoalbum.
Here is my model of album:

```
class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название альбома', max_length=50, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Автор')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата создания', editable=False,
                                      default=datetime.datetime.today())
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', verbose_name='Фото', blank=True, related_name='photo_albums')
    number_of_photos = "something"
```

How can i get number of connected with album photos for each photo album?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store this in the `PhotoAlbum` model. You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

PhotoAlbum.objects.annotate(num_photos=Count('photos'))
```

The `PhotoAlbum` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.num_photos` that will contain the number of related `Photo` objects.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm newbie at django, so my teacher gave me the task to create a model of photoalbum with field for number of photos in this album, this  is needed for future filtering in swagger. Is there a way to store such information in a model?